# How do I make a form reappear after hiding it to display a successful AJAX message?

Tags: jquery, ajax, toggle

I am trying to display a confirmation message after a successful ajax call. A user clicks a link to send a message to another user, which opens up a dialog. After they send the message I hide the form and a simple message such as "message sent" is displayed. However, after the user closes the dialog and reopens it, the form does not reappear and the message is still there.

This is the popup dialog and message form:

```
    <a href="#MessageStudent" class="popUpLink">Message</a>
    <div class="popUpDialog" id="messageStudentDialog">
        <div id="messageStatus"></div>                                      
        <form class="sendMessageForm" id="studentForm" action="" method="POST">     
            <fieldset>
                <input type="hidden" value="317" name="studentID">
                <textarea rows="3" cols="35" name="message"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This is the jQuery handler for clicking the link and the dialog:

```
function popUpDialogs()
{
    $('.popUpLink').each(function()
    {
         if(!$.data(this, 'dialog')) 
         {
            $divDialog = $(this).next('.popUpDialog');
            $.data(this, 'dialog', $divDialog.dialog(
            {
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                title: $divDialog.attr('title')

            }));
         }
    }).on('click',function() 
    { 
        $.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open'); 
        $('form',$divDialog).toggle(); //This is what I'm trying but doesn't work
        return false; 
    });
}
```

This is my AJAX form handler:

```
$('form.sendMessageForm', '.popUpDialog').on('submit', function()
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var form =  $(this);
    var popUpDialog = form.parent();
    var data = new Array();
    var data = form.serialize();
    $.post('',  { sendMessage : data}, function(response)
    {           
        $(form).toggle();//This is what I'm trying but it doesn't work
        $('div#messageStatus', popUpDialog).html("<p>Message Sent!</p>").hide().fadeIn(3000).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000)     //<== wait 3 sec before fading out
          .fadeOut('slow', function()
      {

      });
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript error messages in your Developer Tools console? Do you know that the function is returning success? Are you saying your div#messageStatus pop-up is showing and fading out but the form isn't appearing once the pop-up fades out? You could just call fadeOut('slow') without the function unless you're planning on putting things in there. Is it possible your two toggles are cancelling each other out? Have you broken through the code line-by-line yet?

Comment: There's no error because well...there's nothing wrong with it. It's just the logic I'm struggling with if you get what I mean. I'm saying the messageStatus is fading in after the form hides then the message fades out. My gripe is that what if the user closes the dialog mid-animation? The animation of the message fading in and out is paused until the user reopens the dialog, obviously this is not user friendly. When a user closes the dialog when the dialog appears , the form should reappear when they reopen it.

Comment: Your selectors seem overly complicated to me. I would try giving IDs and selecting just on that rather than `$('form',$(this).next('.popUpDialog'))` Your scenario is difficult to understand. Perhaps you could demonstrate (or simulate) the behavior in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.popUpLink').each(function()
{
     if(!$.data(this, 'dialog')) 
     {
        $divDialog = $(this).next('.popUpDialog');
        $.data(this, 'dialog', $divDialog.dialog(
        {
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: $divDialog.attr('title')

        }));
     }
}).on('click',function() 
{ 
    $.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open'); 
    $('form',this).toggle(); //This is what I'm trying but doesn't work
    return false; 
});
```

Just a thought (not tested) but ... `$('form',this)` - 'this' is referring to the link `.popUpLink`, I believe. And your form isn't inside that link. Use the proper selector for the form you want to show again (either the ID or the class)

Comment: I've tried $divDialog which I've saved as a variable which refers to the dialog and the form is inside the link and that doesn't work as well

Comment: can't you just do `$("#studentForm").show();`?  Or if you need to to be more generic `$(this).next(".popUpDialog").find("form").show();`?

Comment: Stick your work so far into http://jsfiddle.net and I'll have a play. (obviously, leave out the actual ajax calls. just add the clicks and show/hides)

Comment: Hey, cheers. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/BW2Hj/10/

There's two problems:

1. click submit, wait for animation to finish and then close dialog. Reopen dialog. Form does not reappear.

2. Interrupt the animation by closing the dialog mid process then reopen it. Message is still there.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i had done in my project,
i just gave response as 1 or 0 from server 
if deletion is successful just hide div ,you can do it as same like,
this is the code snippest from my project :

```
 $(".deleteDiv").unbind("click").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if ($(".deleteDiv")) {

            var dataString = 'PostId=' + $(this).attr("data-id");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "ajax/deletepost.aspx",
                context: this,
                //                data: { TargetId: "" },
                data: dataString,
                success: function (data) { /* do something here */
                    if(data == 1){
                     $(this).parents("div.story_wrapper").addClass("noData");
                     $(".noData").slideUp();
                    }

                },
                error: function (xhr, type, exception) { alert("Error: " + type); }
            })

        }

    return false;

});
```

It worked 100% and never failed in my project(hopefully!!!!)

and for hiding and showing use classes as flags like i used noData.